# Spring Boot with ReactJS

Tags: spring-mvc, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm trying to build a Spring boot application with ReactJS as front end.
I'm new to React JS, so far I've been using AngularJs & Jquery. Since just adding them as a plugin in my html page would be sufficient I never really felt hard in adding those. But when it comes to ReactJS I see that there are a number of files that needs to be generate in it. Now my question is how do I get these files generated and how does Spring boot load those files automatically.
I'm currently following the below link to create a spring+reactJS application and the below link points out to the files that loads automatically.

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/#_loading_javascript_modules

Can some one please explain or point me in a right direction on how to get these files in a application

Answer (score 2):

if you use maven you can build your react javascript files on *mvn compile* or *mvn spring-boot:run*

include in pom.xml:

```
    <build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>

            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>   <!--Apache 2.0 https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/blob/master/LICENSE  -->

            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <version>1.2</version>

            <configuration>

                <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>

            </configuration>

            <executions>

                <execution>

                    <id>install node and npm</id>

                    <goals>

                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>

                    </goals>

                    <configuration>

                        <nodeVersion>v6.3.1</nodeVersion>

                        <npmVersion>3.9.2</npmVersion>

                    </configuration>

                </execution>

                <execution>

                    <id>npm install</id>

                    <goals>

                        <goal>npm</goal>

                    </goals>

                    <configuration>

                        <arguments>install</arguments>

                    </configuration>

                </execution>

                <execution>

                    <id>webpack build dev</id>

                    <goals>

                        <goal>webpack</goal>

                    </goals>

                </execution>

            </executions>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

this will install npm and build your react modules.
make sure you have a webpack.config.js and package.json in the same directory:

ill include this as an example:
*package.json:*

```html
 {

  "name": "app",

  "version": "0.0.1",

  "description": "",

  "repository": {

    "type": "git",

    "url": ""

  },

  "keywords": [

    "data"
  ],

  "author": "xxx",

  "license": "",

  "bugs": {

    "url": ""

  },

  "homepage": "",

  "dependencies": {

    "react": "^15.3.2",

    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",

    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",

    "rest": "^1.3.1",

    "webpack": "^1.12.2"

  },

  "scripts": {

    "start": "node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --hot",

    "watch": "webpack --watch -d"

  },

  "devDependencies": {

    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",

    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",

    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",

    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",

    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",

    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1"

  }

}
```

*webpack.config.js:*

```html
var path = require('path');

var node_dir = __dirname + '/node_modules';

module.exports = {

    entry: {

        app: './src/main/js/app.jsx',

    },

    devtool: 'sourcemaps',

    cache: false,

    debug: true,

    resolve: {

        alias: {

            'stompjs': node_dir + '/stompjs/lib/stomp.js',

        }

    },

    output: {

        path: __dirname,

        filename: './src/main/resources/static/js/bundled/[name]bundle.js'

    },

    module: {

        loaders: [

            {

                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),

                exclude: /(node_modules)/,

                loader: ['babel-loader'],

                query: {

                    //cacheDirectory: true,

                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']

                }

            }

        ]

    }

};
```

"/src/main/js/app.jsx" -> this is your entrypoint then where you should write your react code. 
In your thymeleaf or jsp files include the bundled javascript. (js/bundled/appbundle.js)

Your app.jsx could look like this:

```html
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import {MainPage} from './mainpage.jsx';

let exampleprop= 2;

ReactDOM.render(<MainPage prop1={exampleprop}  />, document.getElementById('app_root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use webpack for starters. Just download the `react`, `react-dom` and `babel` libraries from react's website and put them to `src/main/resources/static/js` folder and import them on your html tags. For advanced scenarios you will probably need `npm` and `webpack` itself. Java based tools for that kind of development will have limited feature set.

Automatic reloading can be done with `spring-boot-devtools`. Just include it as a dependency and whenever you *Make* your project (by IDE or `mvn compile`) it will reload the server automatically so your changes will get reflected.

Comment: Thanks bekce for responding back!!! As suggested I've started using just the js files as a plugin in my html but when i start my springboot I see 'White Label Error Page'. Can you please help me with a springboot+reactjs helloworld example

Comment: could you zip your project and post it?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this project: https://github.com/vcycyv/react-redux-typescript-saga-webpack-springboot-jpa-pomotodo
It is by me. 
Basically, you may need two modes: development mode and projection mode. The difference is, development mode hot reloads code. According to your question, you are more interested in projection mode. you can use a bundle tool like webpack to generate the bundle.js, and refer the file from index.html. Let me highlight some code snippet from the project above:
in webpack.config.js:

```
    output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../src/main/resources/static')
}
```

in index.html:

```
  <body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="./bundle.js"></script>
```